# DatePicker Control in a C#/XAML Metro Application?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i want to use the DATEPICKER control in my metro application , but it seems there is no datepicker control available  in c#/xaml metro application ,

So have any one of you found a work around for this ?

Please let me know ,

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a DatePicker available from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro/controls/date-picker.aspx). But it is not free.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

I found this from a private solution on codeplex and I sincerely apologize to whomever owns the link ... but you can create a control with the following code:

Xaml File:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.Controls.DatePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ComboBox x:Name="Day" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="Day_SelectionChanged" Width="70" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="Month" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="Day_SelectionChanged" Width="70" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="Year" Grid.Column="2" SelectionChanged="Day_SelectionChanged" Width="100" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the code behind for it its:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MyNamespace.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class DatePicker
    {
        private bool initializing = true; 
        public DatePicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UpdateValues(0, 0);
            Day.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Month.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Year.SelectedIndex = 0;
            initializing = false; 
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowNullProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AllowNull", typeof(bool), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        public bool AllowNull
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowNullProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AllowNullProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

        public DateTime? SelectedDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler SelectedItemChanged; 

        private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ctrl = (DatePicker)d;
            if (ctrl.initializing)
                return;

            ctrl.initializing = true;
            ctrl.UpdateDate();
            ctrl.initializing = false; 

            if (ctrl.SelectedItemChanged != null)
                ctrl.SelectedItemChanged(ctrl, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }

        public void UpdateDate()
        {
            if (SelectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                UpdateValues(SelectedDate.Value.Year, SelectedDate.Value.Month);

                if (AllowNull)
                {
                    Day.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Day;
                    Month.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Month;
                    Year.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Year - 2000 + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    Day.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Day - 1;
                    Month.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Month - 1;
                    Year.SelectedIndex = SelectedDate.Value.Year - 2000;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateValues(0, 0);
                Day.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Month.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Year.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateValues(int year, int month)
        {
            var days = new List<string>();
            if (AllowNull)
                days.Add(" ");
            for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++)//(year != 0 && month != 0 ? DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month) : 31); i++)
                days.Add(i.ToString());

            var months = new List<string>();
            if (AllowNull)
                months.Add(" ");
            for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
                months.Add(i.ToString());

            var years = new List<string>();
            if (AllowNull)
                years.Add(" ");
            for (var i = 2000; i <= 2020; i++)
                years.Add(i.ToString());

            if (Month.SelectedIndex > months.Count - 1)
                Month.SelectedIndex = months.Count - 1; 

            Day.ItemsSource = days;
            Month.ItemsSource = months;
            Year.ItemsSource = years; 
        }

        private void Day_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (initializing)
                return;

            var hour = SelectedDate != null ? SelectedDate.Value.Hour : 0;
            var minute = SelectedDate != null ? SelectedDate.Value.Minute : 0;
            var second = SelectedDate != null ? SelectedDate.Value.Second : 0;

            initializing = true;
            if (AllowNull && (Day.SelectedIndex == 0 || Month.SelectedIndex == 0 || Year.SelectedIndex == 0))
                SelectedDate = null;
            else
            {
                if (AllowNull)
                    SelectedDate = new DateTime(Year.SelectedIndex + 2000 - 1, Month.SelectedIndex, Day.SelectedIndex, hour, minute, second);
                else
                    SelectedDate = new DateTime(Year.SelectedIndex + 2000, Month.SelectedIndex + 1, Day.SelectedIndex + 1, hour, minute, second);
            }

            //if (SelectedItem.HasValue)
            //  UpdateValues(SelectedItem.Value.Year, SelectedItem.Value.Month);
            //else
            //  UpdateValues(0, 0);

            initializing = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now there is a DatePicker control for windwos store apps provided by microsoft. It comes with windows 8.1.

Check here for other new controls:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182878.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [Link](http://www.telerik.com/help/metro-xaml/common-create-application-and-adding-control.html), i think this is what you are looking for.

And before that you should have to be installed [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-metro/overview.aspx) free windows8 rc